# Can I access a variable inside useEffect without use useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-effect, use-state

I want to access a variable inside useEffect hook without use useState. How can I do that?

Here my codes:

```js
let numberOfLessons;

useEffect(() => {
        getLessons()
            .then(response => 
                numberOfLessons = response.data().length // 6
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }, [])


console.log(numberOfLessons) // undefined
```

Comment: You can't access variables declared inside a function from outside that function. What's the  problem in using `useState` ?

Comment: Scoping issue as `let` is block scoped so referencing it outside the defining block is a no no.

Comment: You are saying inside useEffect but accessing it outside? let has a block scope so you can not access it outside.

Comment: First things first, you are trying to access a variable which is declared and available only in your "then" callback function. So answer to your question is no, you should either  use useState or consider to use a state management tool, such as Redux, MobX, etc. if you need to access this variable globally.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this has nothing to do with defining let. Result:  I cannot access a variable inside useEffect without use useState? is it correct?

Comment: In your original post, you defined the variable inside the then callback with `let`. Now you can access this variable anywhere between that specific block of code, ie between `{` and `}`. Now in your edited post, you have moved the declaration up with which now you can access the variable. But you would still print `undefined` because by the time that `console.log` executes, your `numberOfLessons = response.data().length` is waiting in the `callstack` to be picked up by the `event loop`. which means you will get `undefined`, as that is the initial value of your `numberOfLessons` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to physically stop you from doing this.  But the downside is that your variable is not part of the React state.

It's value is initially set to `undefined`.  Later on when you set it to `6` that will not trigger React to re-render the view, so your 6 might not ever appear on the screen.

But perhaps that doesn't matter to you.  If this variable is only used e.g. for logging then it wouldn't matter if React knows about it or not.

---

In your exact example `console.log` is undefined because you are logging *before* the value is set.  This is not really a React specific problem.  That's just how async code works.  If you did

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(numberOfLessons), 5000)
```

then you would get the `6` as expected.